# Is mutex required in Qt, if different threads are invoking same signal of another different thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

Let `class A` is having only one object named as `objectA` and it's being on a separate thread (say "TCP"):

```
connect(&objectA, SIGNAL(MySignal()), &objectA, SLOT(MySlot()));
```

**Note**: I assume that `Qt::AutoConnection` will take care of whether it's `QueuedConnection` or `DirectConnection`. I am OK with any type, which makes it safer.

Now if B (say "Processor") & C (say "Utility") are different threads, which are invoking `MySignal()` with their own convenience.
In the `MySlot()`, some data of `objectA` is getting written.

**Question**:
Do I need mutex-locking to protect data of `A a;`?
OR
The `MySignal()` will be queued automatically and hence the `MySlot()` will get sequentially invoked?

**Use case**: Currently I am having a TCP thread which send/receive data to/from server. At times, 2 threads may send the data at same time. It's likely to run 2 threads in perfect parallel now a days due to multi-processor architecture.

Comment: Those aren't *invoking* the slot - but you've established a *queued connection*, which will serialise the invocations.

Comment: Interesting question but in what use case would that occur ? It would mean you are processing the slot in a thread while other methods from the same object are running in the other threads and potentially emitting the signal. Both the method who emits the signal and the slot-method could then access data from `A a;` at the same time, no matter the connection.

Comment: @ymoreau, let's say the thread of `class A` is a TCP thread which sends data to server. Now thread B and C are sending their own data at their own convenience. This is the use case for me as of now.

Comment: I was not quite right in my first comment - this is an *auto* connection, not a *queued* connection.

Comment: @TobySpeight, I have updated the Qn. Due to complexity, the code example is not possible. Will `Qt::QueuedConnection` will eliminate the need of Mutexes? If possible, plz expand your comment in form of answer with more details.

Comment: I claim that the code example *is* possible.  What do you need - two objects and two threads?  Is it really so hard?

Answer (score 2):

If the object the slot is executed on is in a different thread than the object that does the `emit`, then the call is not sequential. The `emit` will not block. Thus if you access data that the emitting object might be writing to after the `emit`, you need to either synchronize that access with a mutex, or use a blocking connection (which means you're forcing sequential execution, meaning `emit` will block until the slot has returned.)

So, if the `emit` happens on a different thread, and you want it to block, use a blocking connection. If you don't want the `emit` to block, use a mutex to protect the data. If the `emit` happens on the same thread, it's going to be a blocking connection anyway.

However, if the `emit` happens in several threads, then you always need a mutex.

Comment: The language is not clear. Can you plz describe in more details? Who should have `BlockingConnection` and who should have `QueuedConnection`?

Comment: @iammilind If the `emit` happens on a different thread, and you want the `emit` to block, use a blocking connection. If you don't want the `emit` to block, use a mutex to protect the data. If the `emit` happens on the same thread, it's going to be a blocking connection anyway. If the `emit` happens in several threads, then you always need a mutex.

Comment: By any chance is it feasible that fair a low priority thread we use queued connection and for higher priority thread we use blicking connection? Or both threads must use blocking?

Answer (score 1):

Assume those threads have been created on the main thread and since `connect` by default uses `Qt::AutoConnection` and docs say:

> (Default) If the receiver lives in the thread that emits the signal, `Qt::DirectConnection` is used. Otherwise, `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used. The connection type is determined when the signal is emitted.

By the time a thread emits a signal, since sender (the code running in `QThread::run()`) and receiver (the thread who has created the `QThread` object itself) are different threads, `Qt::QueuedConnection` is used. That is:

> The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

So all `MySlot` will be sequentially executed on the main thread.

---

#### Update

You've somewhat changed your question! In general, The following connection means: `MySignal` could be emitted in any threads (i.e. the thread in which you've called `emit MySignal()`), **but** `MySlot` is *only* called in the thread which `objectA` belongs to (i.e. thread affinity). If those threads are the same, the slot is executed synchronously.

```
connect(&objectA, SIGNAL(MySignal()), &objectA, SLOT(MySlot()));
```

Comment: Do you mean that if from 2 different processors, if `thread B & C` together invoke `MySignal()`, then without any mutexes in the slot method, Qt will make the `MySlot()` invocations sequential? That implies that Qt must be using mutexes.

Comment: Yes. You're right. For `Qt::QueuedConnection` Qt internally uses mutexes to put an event to the receiver's event loop.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need mutex-locking to protect data of A a;?

In case you are accessing `a`'s data outside of the thread in which `a`'s event loop lives, yes you do need a lock.

Answer (score 0):

There's something suspect in your design.

Normally, signals are `protected`, and emitted only from code running in that object's thread.  A more conventional design would have objects B and C emit *their own* signals, and you would connect those signals to the slots of `objectA`.

Whilst what you have might *work*, it will be hard to reason about, and it's probably a good time to review your design before it becomes too tangled to understand what happens in which thread.

Comment: Let's imagine that objects of `B & C` have their own versions of `MySignal()` which are connected with `A::MySlot()` with `QueuedConnetion`. Even in that case, is it possible that `MySlot()` will be executed in sequential way? If yes, then that means that Qt must be using mutexes internally to make sure that both the calls are sequential.

Comment: If the `B` and `C` objects emit their own signals, then yes, those will be queued until the event loop of the `A` thread processes them.  Yes, Qt performs the appropriate locking when it posts events.  See `QCoreApplication::postEvent()` and `QAbstractEventDispatcher::processEvents()`

Comment: _"and emitted only from code running in that object's thread."_ That's wrong!

Comment: @Hiim, I guess you have a different definition of "normal", then.  (That said, I think your answer is clearer and more directly answers the question - I've voted).